# WordPress Feedback popup with date saved into table

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax

Spending now more then 2 days of searching and testing all kind of plugins, I need some help.

I need a Feedback popup plugin with these tasks:

- front-end pop-up with main question + text area for customer answer + submit button
- designable layout
- saves the input data into a table
- text design in admin
- in admin a list of all feedbacks
- email reply to customers
- variable places to start popup on a page
- jquery + ajax + php coded

Maybe someone of you knows a plugin that I can simple recode to fit my needs.
Thanks in advance for looking into my question and (I hope) some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a combination of two plugins.

1. First a lightbox plugin [Lightbox Plugins on the WP Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=lightbox)
2. Then using Ninja Forms plugin, which is free [Ninja Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/)
3. Then create a lightbox following the instructions from the lightbox plugin
4. Then create a form in Ninja Forms
5. And then lastly add the form shortcode inside the lightbox

This is the method I would use except I code my own lightbox and use [Gravity Forms](http://gravityforms.com), but that is a premium plugin and ninja forms works fine.